# SQL Server: FULL JOIN Select, Managing Duplicates between Table A & B

Tags: sql-server

I have a complicated (to me) SQL Server join of two tables in a query. I have two tables that perform the same function with a similar structure (but updated separately), and am writing a query to find the differences between the two so that they may be better maintained in relative sync. The tables are similar to the following:

**Edit**: Please the SQL Fiddle link at the bottom for added clarity.

```
Table A
+-----+---------+----------------+------------+-----------+
| ID  | Product | ValidationDate | ValidValue | ValidHour |
+-----+---------+----------------+------------+-----------+
| 991 |       1 | 1/1/2015       |        100 | 8:00      |
| 992 |       1 | 1/2/2015       |        100 | 8:00      |
| 993 |       1 | 1/2/2015       |        100 | 8:00      |
| 994 |       1 | 1/3/2015       |         88 | 9:00      |
| 995 |       2 | 1/1/2015       |         98 | 9:00      |
| 996 |       2 | 1/1/2015       |         75 | 10:00     |
| 997 |       2 | 1/5/2015       |         80 | 10:00     |
+-----+---------+----------------+------------+-----------+

Table B
+----+---------+----------------+------------+-----------+
| ID | Product | ValidationDate | ValidValue | ValidHour |
+----+---------+----------------+------------+-----------+
|  1 |       1 | 1/1/2015       |        100 | 8:00      |
|  2 |       1 | 1/2/2015       |        100 | 8:00      |
|  3 |       1 | 1/3/2015       |         88 | 9:00      |
|  4 |       2 | 1/1/2015       |         98 | 8:00      |
|  5 |       2 | 1/1/2015       |         75 | 10:00     |
+----+---------+----------------+------------+-----------+
```

The query is intended to return the differences between the two tables by `Product`, `ValidationDate`, `ValidValue`, and `ValidHour`. If there's a mismatch between the two, I want to display the results from both tables for the particular `Product`, `ValidationDate`, `ValidValue`, and `ValidHour` as follows:

```
+---------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+--------+
| Product | ValidDate | A_Value | A_Grade | B_Value | B_Hour |
+---------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+--------+
|       1 | 1/2/2015  |     100 | 8:00    |         |        |
|       1 | 1/2/2015  |     100 | 8:00    |         |        |
|       1 | 1/2/2015  |         |         |     100 | 8:00   |
|       2 | 1/5/2015  |      80 | 10:00   |         |        |
+---------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+--------+
```

As you see, there are uneven identical entries found between Table A (`ID` 992,993) and Table B (`ID` 2), so both Table A entries, along with the single Table B entries are output. In addition, Table A contains an entry not found in Table B, which is displayed as well.

I initially created a statement similar to the following:

```
SELECT Product, ValidDate, a.Value, a.Grade, b.Value, b.Hour
FROM Table_A a
FULL OUTER JOIN Table_B b
  ON a.Product = b.Product AND
     a.ValidDate = b.ValidDate AND
     a.ValidValue = b.ValidValue AND
     a.ValidHour = b.ValidHour AND
WHERE (a.Product IS NULL AND
     a.ValidDate IS NULL AND
     a.ValidValue IS NULL AND
     a.ValidHour IS NULL) 
    OR
    (b.Product IS NULL AND
     b.ValidDate IS NULL AND
     b.ValidValue IS NULL AND
     b.ValidHour IS NULL)
```

However, it doesn't really work because even though it returns the correct result for the third column in the desired output above (where a single row exists in one table but not at all in the other), it ignores cases where there are uneven duplicate entries between tables.

How can I accomplish what I need in the query?

**Edit:** I've created a clearer example of my situation and desire in SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8a92/4 I've commented the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I used 2 table expressions and joined them equally on all the columns except for the aggregated column.  Where there's a variance on the aggregated column the query returns the row.  Hope this helps.

```
    With A as 
(
    select Date, Product, ValidValue, SomeValue2, 
        count(*) as NumOfOccurences
    from dbo.TableA
    group by Date, Product, ValidValue, SomeValue2
)
, 
b as
(
    select Date, Product, ValidValue, SomeValue2, 
            count(*) as NumOfOccurences
    from dbo.TableB
    group by Date, Product, ValidValue, SomeValue2

)

select *
from a join b on A.date = b.date and
                      A.product = b.product and
                      A.ValidValue = b.ValidValue and
                      A.SomeValue2 = b.SomeValue2 and
                      A.NumOfOccurences <> b.NumOfOccurences;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is, while probably not impossible, is going to be very involved, code-wise. All DBMSs operate according to sets and one of the foremost characteristics of a set is that duplicates are not allowed. When you allow multiple entries with identical non-key values you are no longer working with a set.

By far the simplest solution would be to truncate TableB and just copy over everything in TableA.

```
truncate TableB;
insert into TableB( ... )
   select ... from TableA;
```

I assume the ID field of both tables are auto generating. I also assume there is something about the tables that prevent triggers from keeping them in synch on the fly. That would be the optimal long-term solution.

Comment: If the tables are in fact supposed to have the same contents than the optimal solution would be to remove the secondary table entirely. :)

Comment: There are many reasons for propagating the contents of a master table to one or more copies -- generally on different servers on remote locations. We don't know the particulars, we can just assume there is a good reason. Actually, in thinking about it, the best solution might be a materialized view that resynchs on their update schedule. There may be some drawbacks, such as lots of network traffic during the synch, but it may well be possible

Answer (score 0):

OK. Thanks for the sqlfiddle. That makes this fairly simple to deal with. I am going to paste your fiddle create here just for completeness sake.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableA](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Product] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ValidValue] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SomeValue2] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableB](
    [ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Product] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ValidValue] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [SomeValue2] [smallint] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO TableA SELECT 991,1,'1/1/15',75, 7;
INSERT INTO TableA SELECT 992,1,'1/2/15',100,8; --these two are identical values in TableA,
INSERT INTO TableA SELECT 993,1,'1/2/15',100,8; --Possibly erroneous duplication 

INSERT INTO TableB SELECT 1,  1,'1/2/15',100,8; --In TableB, there is only a single matching value
INSERT INTO TableB SELECT 1,  1,'1/3/15',90, 6;
```

So now in order to be able to identify duplicates you need to also use a ROW_NUMBER. We can do this by utilizing a cte for each of your base tables. Then a slight modification to the join and it will nonmatched duplicates for EITHER TableA OR TableB

```
with MyTableA as
(
    select *
        , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Product, Date order by ID) as RowNum
    from TableA a
)
, MyTableB as
(
    select * 
    , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Product, Date order by ID) as RowNum
    from TableB
)

SELECT  CASE WHEN a.Date IS NULL 
             THEN b.Date
             ELSE a.Date
             END Date,
        CASE WHEN a.Product IS NULL 
             THEN b.Product
             ELSE a.Product
             END Product,
        a.ValidValue A_ValidValue, 
        a.SomeValue2 A_SomeValue2, 
        b.ValidValue B_ValidValue, 
        b.SomeValue2 B_SomeValue2
FROM MyTableA a
FULL OUTER JOIN MyTableB b
  ON a.Product = b.Product AND
     a.Date = b.Date AND
     a.ValidValue = b.ValidValue AND
     a.SomeValue2 = b.SomeValue2
     AND a.RowNum = b.RowNum
WHERE (a.Product IS NULL OR
     a.Date IS NULL OR
     a.ValidValue IS NULL OR
     a.SomeValue2 IS NULL) 
    OR
    (b.Product IS NULL OR
     b.Date IS NULL OR
     b.ValidValue IS NULL OR
     b.SomeValue2 IS NULL)
```

I deleted my previous answer and the sqlfiddle link was in the comments. Here is a link to the original sqlfiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8a92/11